# Cmake additional includes

Tags: include, cmake

How to set additional includes for cmake project (not in CmakeLists.txt) or how to include additional *.cmake file for project without overwriting this project CMakeLists.txt.

I try `-DCMAKE_C_IMPLICIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES=<...>` and `-DCMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES=<...>`, but there is no effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add additional include directories by specifying them in the variables `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` upon invoking cmake:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-I /path/to/dir" ..
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I forgot about that possibility.

Comment: This overwrites the default CMake values for `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` which is probably not a desired side effect.  Also, for this to work on Windows, I think the path needs to be enclosed in escaped quotes and not have a space after the `I`: `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-I\"/path/to/dir\""`